# Basic openssl encryption script issues

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm currently working through a series of exercises in an attempt to improve my bash scripting knowledge.

The exercise I am working on is as follows:
Write a script called encrypt.sh that's used to encrypt files. 
Here are the requirements for the script:

> 1. It must use openssl to encrypt files.
> 2. It must take the name of a file to encrypt as a parameter
> 3. When it encrypts a file it must put the encrypted version in a file
>      with the same name but ".enc" appended.
> 4. It must be safe to run on a system with other users. That is, it
>      must not pass any passwords as command line arguments.
> 5. It must read the password to use from an environment variable called
>      ENCRYPTION_KEY.
> 6. If that environment variable is not set, it should prompt the user
>      to enter a password and use that instead.
> 7. It should display an error if no parameter is provided and exit with
>      exit code 2.
> 8. It should display a message if the user calls the script with a
>      --help switch.
> 9. It should work with files with spaces in the name.

I feel as if my current script has satisfied requirements 1-5,7-8.
However I am somewhat floundered as to 6 and 9.

Any feedback on my current workings, or solutions to my missing requirements would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
usage="Usage: Enter the name of the file you would like to encrypt as a parameter, eg. $0 words"
ENCRYPTION_KEY="1234"
export ENCRYPTION_KEY
openssl enc -e -aes256 -in "$1" -out "$1".enc -pass env:ENCRYPTION_KEY
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    echo $usage
fi

if test -z ${1}
    then
        echo "${0} :ERROR: No parameters provided. Please see -h or --help for usage." 1>&2
        exit 1
fi

#DECODE (script is not required to decode, just here for testing purposes)
#openssl enc -d -aes256 -in words.enc -out words.enc.dec -pass env:ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

Comment: you should put the checks for the `--help` switch and for no arguments before, not after the `openssl enc` command. You should also change `if test -z ${1}` to `if test -z "$1"` in order to satisfy point 9.

Comment: also, you shouldn't override `ENCRYPTION_KEY` if you want to be able to pass it to the script via the environment; btw, though that's a requirement, it's usually a stupid idea to pass password via the environment.

Answer (score 0):

For #6, [the `read` bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) will be helpful. For #9, make sure that the variable names are in double quotes everywhere you use them.